# Weird error when client connecting to host + Netcode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Character animations are not producing any errors if only one player connects to the game.
But when the client connects to the host, the animations are visibly working correctly, but I'm getting this error when moving the player and triggering animations.

*Note: All animations are visible for host and client, but sometimes when I jump on client the player is getting stuck in air*

Here is my error:

```
[Netcode] [DestinationState To Transition Info] Layer (0) does not exist!
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkLog:LogError (string) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.4.0/Runtime/Logging/NetworkLog.cs:34)
Unity.Netcode.Components.NetworkAnimator:UpdateAnimationState (Unity.Netcode.Components.NetworkAnimator/AnimationState) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.4.0/Components/NetworkAnimator.cs:1181)
Unity.Netcode.Components.NetworkAnimator:SendAnimStateServerRpc (Unity.Netcode.Components.NetworkAnimator/AnimationMessage,Unity.Netcode.ServerRpcParams) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.4.0/Components/NetworkAnimator.cs:1261)
Unity.Netcode.Components.NetworkAnimator:__rpc_handler_4140764492 (Unity.Netcode.NetworkBehaviour,Unity.Netcode.FastBufferReader,Unity.Netcode.__RpcParams)
Unity.Netcode.RpcMessageHelpers:Handle (Unity.Netcode.NetworkContext&,Unity.Netcode.RpcMetadata&,Unity.Netcode.FastBufferReader&,Unity.Netcode.__RpcParams&) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.4.0/Runtime/Messaging/Messages/RpcMessages.cs:70)
Unity.Netcode.ServerRpcMessage:Handle (Unity.Netcode.NetworkContext&) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.4.0/Runtime/Messaging/Messages/RpcMessages.cs:117)
Unity.Netcode.MessagingSystem:ReceiveMessage<Unity.Netcode.ServerRpcMessage> (Unity.Netcode.FastBufferReader,Unity.Netcode.NetworkContext&,Unity.Netcode.MessagingSystem) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.4.0/Runtime/Messaging/MessagingSystem.cs:541)
Unity.Netcode.MessagingSystem:HandleMessage (Unity.Netcode.MessageHeader&,Unity.Netcode.FastBufferReader,ulong,single,int) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.4.0/Runtime/Messaging/MessagingSystem.cs:414)
Unity.Netcode.MessagingSystem:ProcessIncomingMessageQueue () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.4.0/Runtime/Messaging/MessagingSystem.cs:434)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager:OnNetworkEarlyUpdate () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.4.0/Runtime/Core/NetworkManager.cs:1443)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager:NetworkUpdate (Unity.Netcode.NetworkUpdateStage) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.4.0/Runtime/Core/NetworkManager.cs:1375)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkUpdateLoop:RunNetworkUpdateStage (Unity.Netcode.NetworkUpdateStage) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.4.0/Runtime/Core/NetworkUpdateLoop.cs:185)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkUpdateLoop/NetworkEarlyUpdate/<>c:<CreateLoopSystem>b__0_0 () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.4.0/Runtime/Core/NetworkUpdateLoop.cs:208)
```

Video showing animation bug:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b068OuQEsjg

[My NetworkAnimator override for coop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxjSA.png)

and my animator component
[image: my animator component]

There is nothing on the internet about it. I only found someone who suggested removing idle animations

Comment: Hey man, I'm facing the same issue. Have you been able to solve it by any chance?

Comment: did you google: DestinationState To Transition Info ... ?   Lots of info

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Sorceri yes, not a lot actually. Only one such case was reported and the fix is associated to the use of blend trees, which I am not using.

Comment: Stupid question: what happens if you use the newest version of NGO (1.5.2) - seeing as you're currently on 1.4.0?

Comment: @11belowstudio I updated to the latest 1.6.0 version and the same issue is occurring